# PostgreSQL treating TEXT as JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a TEXT column in my table (it's actually 'character varying'), but the data in the column is valid json.  How can I access fields in this column using Postgres 9.3's new JSON functions?

What I basically want is a way to be able to do:

```
SELECT mycolumn->'myfield' from mytable;
```

Do I need to convert the entire column to the native JSON datatype, or is there an easy/efficient way to cast the cells?

Comment: So you tried casting them inside your query and it didn't work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a [type cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS):

```
SELECT mycolumn::json->'myfield' FROM mytable;
```